# Autohotkey. How to make work both `a hotkey` and `a hotkey+key`?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have two hotkeys in my script. Namely `LWin Up` and `LWin+LAlt Up`. I've tried to do it like that:

```
LAlt & LWin Up:: ;I've also tried commenting out the first
LWin & LAlt Up:: ;or the second line
LWin Up::
  msgbox, % A_ThisHotkey
return
```

But the output depends on the order in which keys were pressed and released. The time between releasing the first and the second key also affects the result. Sometimes I get two MessageBoxes, sometimes just one and sometimes even none at all (the first line is commented out, press alt, press win, release win, release alt). How do I make it work? To be clear: I want to get only one MessageBox.

In the answer it would be great to see a script that provides full information about the hotkey pressed and the order in which the keys it consist of were pressed and released. *Only one hotkey should be triggered after releasing `a hotkey+key` combo.

Answer (score 2):

You can not put them altogether.
you should use something like this:

```
altPressed := false

LAlt & LWin Up::
    msgbox, % A_ThisHotkey
return

LWin & LAlt Up::
    msgbox, % A_ThisHotkey
    altPressed := true
return

LWin Up::
    if !altPressed {
        msgbox, % A_ThisHotkey
    }
    altPressed := false
return
```

If what  you want to do instead of `msgbox` is too spreaded in my code you can use the below one:

```
SetTimer, toDo, 10

toDo:
    if doWhatEver {
        ;; HERE DESCRIBE WHAT TO DO
        doWhatEver := false
    }
return

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

altPressed := false
doWhatEver := false

LAlt & LWin Up::
    doWhatEver := true
return

LWin & LAlt Up::
    doWhatEver := true
    altPressed := true
return

LWin Up::
    if !altPressed {
        doWhatEver := true
    }
    altPressed := false
return
```

Comment: It doesn't work, but I've got the idea. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @user2277240 it works. there is a little problem in which , when you press `alt + Win` then because you first release Win then release alt it invokes `altPressed := true` causing `Lwin Up` not to run on first press. the second time  you press it it works (I mean LWin key individually).

Answer (score 0):

TechJS's answer wasn't working exactly as I wish so here is my script. It detects the order in which the keys were pressed and released, and doesn't depend on time between keys pressed/released.

```
global firstPressed := ""

LAlt::
  altDown := true
  if (winDown)
    return
  firstPressed := "!"
return

LWin::
  winDown := true
  if (altDown)
    return
  firstPressed := "#"
return

LAlt Up::
  altDown := false
  if (!winDown) {
    if (comboJustUp) {
      comboJustUp := false
      return
    }
    msgbox !
  }
  if (winDown) {
    comboJustUp := true
    if (firstPressed = "#") 
      msgbox #!!.
    if (firstPressed = "!")
      msgbox !#!.
  }
return

LWin Up::
  winDown := false
  if (!altDown) {
    if (comboJustUp) {
      comboJustUp := false
      return
    }
    msgbox #
  }
  if (altDown) {
    comboJustUp := true
    if (firstPressed = "!") ; \here is one bug though. If you switch theese
      msgbox !##.           ; /two lines
    if (firstPressed = "#") ; \with theese
      msgbox #!#.           ; /two. It won't work correctly for some reason
  }
return
```